# Get Ajax variable from the PHP foreach loops

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax (jquery version) script and very short php function and they works fine without problem.
When I submit the value from the form input are, the ajax will work to send and get result from 
the php script, in this case to get a total amount of the book order.
The Ajax script and html section are as follows:

```
     <script language="JavaScript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("form").mouseout( function() {
      // get field value

      var qtyVal = $('#qty').val();
      // use HTTP GET get ajax 
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  'getSunBody.php',
        data: { qty : qtyVal,
                 }, 
        success: function(data) {
           //get xml value
                    $('#result').html($(data).find('qty').text()); 
           $('#result1').html($(data).find('caution').text());   

        } 
      });    
      return false;
   });
});
</script>


<body>
Total price:<div id="result" class="box" style="height=350px;"></div><div id="result1" class="box" style="height=350px;"></div>
<form>
  <p>
    <label>quantity: </label>
    <input type="text" id="qty" name="qty"/> 
    <br/>
       <input type="submit" value="submit">
    total price:</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

And the following php script serving as xml also works fine with above ajax request:

```
<?php
// XML document
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
// get field values
$qty = (isset($_POST["qty"]) ) ? $_POST["qty"] : $_GET["qty"];

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>";

echo "<datetime>"; 
echo "<qty>" . $qty*100 . "</qty>";

$total=$qty*100;
if ($total==0)
    echo "<caution>"."please input number!"."</caution>";
    else if ($total<=500)
    echo "<caution>"."you shoud buy more!"."</caution>";
    echo "";

echo "</datetime>";

?>
```

However when I combine the above scripts with my shopping cart foreach loops, it doesn't work and the ajax script failed to get variables from the form input area. I don't know if it is a variable scope issue (globals or local)? or anything else?

The following is the total script I would like to fixed with:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("form").mouseout( function() {
      // get value from the form

      var qtyVal = $('#qty').val();
      // get 
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  'getSunBody.php',
        data: { qty : qtyVal,
                 }, 
        success: function(data) {
           // get XML value
           $('#result').html($(data).find('qty').text()); 
           $('#result1').html($(data).find('caution').text());   

        } 
      });    
      return false;
   });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
  <th>no</th>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>price</th>
  <th>qty</th>
  <th>update</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach( $_SESSION["psn"] as $i => $data ){
?>
<form action="sessionCartUpdate.php">
<input type="hidden" name="psn" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["psn"][$i];?>">
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $_SESSION["psn"][$i];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $_SESSION["pname"][$i];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $_SESSION["price"][$i];?></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["qty"][$i];?>"></td>
  <input type="submit" name="qty" 
  <td><input type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="update" />
      <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="delete" />
      </td>
</tr>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
<tr><td colsan="5">total amount:<div id="result" class="box" style="height=350px;"></div><div id="result1" class="box" style="height=350px;"></div></td></td>
</table>
<p><a href="sessionProdList.php">continue to shop</a>
<p><a href="sessionCartToDb.php">Put your order</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I would be very grateful if anyone can offer kind or possible suggestion or advice?
My goal is to put different number (variables) in the "input area" (name or id as "qty") throught the using of ajax to get a total amount of price and show the result in the div box (id="result" or "result1").

Comment: id is supposed to be unique `id="qty"` you can use class also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the `id` attribute with class because id is supposed to be unique in the dom and using class you can do a loop to get all quantities of the items in the cart

Another thing i have noticed that you have made the an individual form foreach item in the cart there should be one form having the multiple fields,also remove this line `<input type="submit" name="qty"` it doesent makes sense

```
<form action="sessionCartUpdate.php">
<?php
foreach( $_SESSION["psn"] as $i => $data ){
?>

<input type="hidden" name="psn" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["psn"][$i];?>">
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $_SESSION["psn"][$i];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $_SESSION["pname"][$i];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $_SESSION["price"][$i];?></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="qty" name="qty[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["qty"][$i];?>"></td>

  <td><input type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="update" />
      <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="delete" />
      </td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("form").mouseout( function() {
var qtyVal =0;
$( ".qty" ).each(function() {
  qtyVal =qtyVal + parseInt($(this).val()); 
});      
      // get 
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  'getSunBody.php',
        data: { qty : qtyVal,
                 }, 
        success: function(data) {
           // get XML value
           $('#result').html($(data).find('qty').text()); 
           $('#result1').html($(data).find('caution').text());   

        } 
      });    
      return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow, Amazing! It is an powerful and reliable solution! With your kind help my shopping cart now runs smoothly without any problem!

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your effort and great solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
// get field values
$qty = (isset($_POST["qty"]) ) ? $_POST["qty"] : $_GET["qty"];
```

Instead of using both $_GET and $_POST, you can use $_REQUEST which will give data from either POST or GET.

Comment: Thank you very much for this prompt answer!