# Get Ajax variable from the PHP foreach loops (part II)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Due to dianuj's great help I solved my Ajax looping issue yesterday.
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145838/get-ajax-variable-from-the-php-foreach-loops)!

The solution helps me to send and get quantity variable (class="qty") every time I change the number in the input area.

Now I want to revise my Ajax and PHP loop a little bit to get the "total" variable (the quantity * the price).
I try to get the "price" variable by puting an "hidden" input area with price values.(please see the following script attached).The script get the variable of quantity (class="qty") and price (class="price") without problem.

However, when I put different quantity the script only picks the very first price and multiplies my changed quantity number.

For example, I have three items in the function with three differnt prices:
1. apple $1     x1
2. orange $10    x3
3. banana $2     x4

the script result will show $1 * (2+3+4) instead the correct $1*2+$10*3+$2*4
(the ajax script still gets the variable of price and quantity without problem).

My Ajax and PHP loops are as follows, it seems they can get and send the qty and price variable without problem (but only the fixed price of the very first item):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("form").mouseleave( function() {

 //get qty value and price value from the loop

var totalVal =0;
$( ".qty" ).each(function() {
  totalVal += ($(this).val()*$(".price").val()); 
});      

      // get 
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  'getSunBody.php',
        data: { 
              //sent the total variable to php script (xml)
              total : totalVal,
                 }, 
        success: function(data) {
           // get XML value
           $('#result').html($(data).find('total').text()); 
           $('#result1').html($(data).find('caution').text());   

        } 
      });    
      return false;
   });

   });
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="display">
<form action="sessionCartUpdate.php">
<table width="780" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<?php
foreach( $_SESSION["psn"] as $i => $data ){
?>

<input type="hidden" name="psn" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["psn"][$i];?>">
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" font color="black"><?php echo $_SESSION["psn"][$i];?></td>
  <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $_SESSION["pname"][$i];?></td>
  <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $_SESSION["price"][$i];?></td>
  <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="text" class="qty" name="qty[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["qty"][$i];?>"></td>

    <input type="hidden" class="price" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["price"][$i];?>" >

  <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="update" />
      <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="delete" />
      </td>
</tr><br />

<?php
}
?>
<tr><td colspan="5" align="center">the total:<div id="result" class="box" style="height=350px;"></div><div id="result1" class="box" style="height=350px;"></div>
<div id="result2" class="box" style="height=350px;"></div></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I also include my php script as follows serving as xml for the ajax script above:

```
<?php
// XML
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");

//get total value ("qty * price") from the ajax

$total = (isset($_POST["total"]) ) ? $_POST["total"] : $_GET["total"];

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>";

echo "<caculation>"; 

echo "<total>" . $total . "</total>";


if ($total==0)
    echo "<caution>"."please put number!"."</caution>";
    else if ($total<=500)
    echo "<caution>"."You should buy more!"."</caution>";
    echo "";

echo "</caculation>";

?>
```

I would be very grateful you could offer invaluble advice to help me fix the above bug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem the `.each` loop is for qty not for the price so it is picking the first price because the loop is for qty not for the price you should do something like this

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("form").mouseleave( function() {

 //get qty value and price value from the loop

var totalVal =0;
$( ".qty" ).each(function(i) {
  totalVal += ($(this).val()*$(".price:eq("+i+")").val()); 
});      

      // get 
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  'getSunBody.php',
        data: { 
              //sent the total variable to php script (xml)
              total : totalVal,
                 }, 
        success: function(data) {
           // get XML value
           $('#result').html($(data).find('total').text()); 
           $('#result1').html($(data).find('caution').text());   

        } 
      });    
      return false;
   });

   });
</script>
```

Use the index of `.each` loop and get the price placed at that index i have used the jquery selector `:eq(index here)` and i believe there will be price value for each quantity

Comment: I am very very grateful for your prompt and powerful solution which always rid off my headaches overnight! Sincerely thankfulness to Mr Dianuj!

Comment: @PeterRen kindly read this  :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question  and you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I haven't confirmed the following code, but it should at least get you on the right track

```
var totalVal =0;
$('.qty').each(function() {
    var price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').val();
    totalVal += ($(this).val()*price);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Anders for this kind sugggestion too!